# VS Code: "Open Folder" make my PySpark not work?

Tags: python, apache-spark, visual-studio-code, pyspark, anaconda

I am using Anaconda on Windows 10 x64. I'm using VS Code. Recently I successfully ran the following:

(I)

```
import pyspark
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
spark=SparkSession.builder.master("local[1]").appName("local").getOrCreate()
rdd=spark.sparkContext.parallelize([1,2,3,4,56])
print(rdd.count())
```

Then I clicked file->open folder and opened a folder, so now it appears in a pane on the left-hand side of my screen. **Question #1:** **What does this do**? I used to think that it was just a quick way to see some frequently-used files.

Now that my folder is in my left-hand pane, the above code errors out (see below), with an error that includes the phrase `Python worker failed to connect back.`. **Question #2: Why does this happen?**

**Question #3: If I want to be able to avoid the above error while also having a folder open in VS Code, what should I do? Any ideas about what settings I should look at?**

If I close the folder, my code works again.

-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

**The Error:** Every time it gives me a slightly different error, but it always begins with something like this:

```
Py4JJavaError                             Traceback (most recent call last)
\\pathtomyfile\temp.py in 
----> 240 spark.createDataFrame(pandas_df).toDF(*columns).show()

C:\Spark\spark-3.1.1-bin-hadoop2.7\python\pyspark\sql\dataframe.py in show(self, n, truncate, vertical)
    482         """
    483         if isinstance(truncate, bool) and truncate:
--> 484             print(self._jdf.showString(n, 20, vertical))
    485         else:
    486             print(self._jdf.showString(n, int(truncate), vertical))

C:\Spark\spark-3.1.1-bin-hadoop2.7\python\lib\py4j-0.10.9-src.zip\py4j\java_gateway.py in __call__(self, *args)
   1302 
   1303         answer = self.gateway_client.send_command(command)
-> 1304         return_value = get_return_value(
   1305             answer, self.gateway_client, self.target_id, self.name)
   1306 

C:\Spark\spark-3.1.1-bin-hadoop2.7\python\pyspark\sql\utils.py in deco(*a, **kw)
    109     def deco(*a, **kw):
    110         try:
--> 111             return f(*a, **kw)
    112         except py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError as e:
    113             converted = convert_exception(e.java_exception)

C:\Spark\spark-3.1.1-bin-hadoop2.7\python\lib\py4j-0.10.9-src.zip\py4j\protocol.py in get_return_value(answer, gateway_client, target_id, name)
    324             value = OUTPUT_CONVERTER[type](answer[2:], gateway_client)
    325             if answer[1] == REFERENCE_TYPE:
--> 326                 raise Py4JJavaError(
    327                     "An error occurred while calling {0}{1}{2}.\n".
    328                     format(target_id, ".", name), value)

Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o77.showString.
: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 3.0 failed 1 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.0 in stage 3.0 (TID 3) (blablabla executor driver): org.apache.spark.SparkException: Python worker failed to connect back.
<a bunch more stuff after that>
```

(It's always "Task 0 in stage x failed y times", but x isn't always 3 and y isn't always 1.)

-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

**Other Results:** I get a similar error if I run the following:

(II)

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
spark=SparkSession.builder.master("local[1]").appName("local").getOrCreate()

pandas_df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,100, size=(5,5)))
columns = ["col"+str(i) for i in range(5)]
print(columns)
display(pandas_df.head())

spark.createDataFrame(pandas_df).toDF(*columns).show()
```

I don't get an error if I run the following:

(III)

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
spark=SparkSession.builder.master("local[1]").appName("local").getOrCreate()

rocks = spark.read.format("csv").option("header", "true").load("C:\\rocksamples.csv")
rocks.show(10)
```

Also, none of the above three code blocks (I, II, III) gives an error if I run it from an .ipynb file inside the folder I opened.

-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

**Background:** I have the following files and folders on my machine:

- Anaconda directory: C:\users\me\Anaconda3
- Spark directory: C:\Spark\spark-3.1.1-bin-hadoop2.7
- Java directory: C:\Spark\java\jre1.8.0_231
- Nothing called pyspark in C:\users\me\Anaconda3\Lib\site-packages
- a .csv file at C:\rocksamples.csv
- Winutils file in C:\Hadoop\bin\winutils.exe

My current environment variables (which I would like to clean up but now I'm afraid to) include the following:

- HADOOP_HOME=C:\Hadoop
- JAVA_HOME=C:\Spark\java\jre1.8.0_231
- Path=(other stuff);C:\Spark\spark-3.1.1-bin-hadoop2.7\bin;C:\Spark\java\jre1.8.0_231\bin
- PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON=jupyter
- PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON_OPTS=notebook
- PYSPARK_PYTHON=python
- PYTHONPATH=C:\Spark\spark-3.1.1-bin-hadoop2.7\python
- SPARK_HOME=C:\Spark\spark-3.1.1-bin-hadoop2.7

I think Python is finding the correct PySpark, because if I try `from pyspark import this_does_not_exist` I get  `ImportError: cannot import name 'this_does_not_exist' from 'pyspark' (C:\Spark\spark-3.1.1-bin-hadoop2.7\python\pyspark\__init__.py)` .

​

The folder I opened using "open folder" in VS Code is on a UNC path containing a space (i.e. \\blablabla\bla\my folder).

Comment: VS Code as an editor, when we use it to open the project folder, it will display the files and structure in it on the left side of VS Code for us to view. For using python modules in VS Code, we usually use pip or conda commands to install the modules, and the python modules recognized by VS Code are stored in "\Lib\site-packages\" of the python environment currently in use.

Comment: Thanks a lot @JillCheng! Does that mean that there might be a separate environment associated with the folder that I opened?

Comment: -In VS Code, if you are using a virtual environment, the folder of this environment (the python module is stored in) exists in the currently used project, you could refer to the content of this link: [Python environments in VS Code.](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/environments#_select-and-activate-an-environment)